# How does number of shots (number of times the computation is repeated) affects time complexity

Tags: ibm-q-experience, complexity-theory

I want to know what happens to the time complexity in terms of big O analysis

Answer (score 3):

Number of shots tells you how many times you repeat algorithm run. It is not connected with a complexity of algorithm itself.

Running time of simulation depends on number of shots linearly, so something what you can call "total complexity" is given by complexity of an algorithm multiplied by number of shots.